# .CSV files generated by iOS application not readable in Windows

Tags: ios, objective-c, windows, macos, csv

I have created a .csv file inside my application using Obj C and attached it to an email which sends. All of this works fine and when the file attachment is opened using OSX the file name reads as I expect; "example.csv".

However, when I try this in windows the file extension is no longer visible and the "file is not readable". When I change the name of the file and add .csv on the end of it it becomes readable.

**Why is the file exstention lost after downloading the attachment to a windows computer?**

Here is where I define "FilePath";

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Jobs"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
FilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Jobs/%@.csv",proposalNumber]];
```

Here is the code used for generating the .csv file;

```
// Creates a temporary GPS object that we will use to save our database as a .CSV file.
    GPS *saveGPS = [[GPS alloc] init];
    @synchronized(FilePath) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:FilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        // Creates a file handler which will allow us to write to our file.
        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:FilePath];
        // Creates and writes the first line to our CSV file, which tells the program reading it what the column titles are.
        NSString *csvTitleString =@"Source/Receiver, Latitude, Longitude";
        [myHandle writeData:[csvTitleString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // Creates initializes another string object which will hold each line we want to write.
        NSString *csvString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        // Declares an array and fills it with all GPS objects found in our Database.
        NSArray *allGPS = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[database getAllbyProposal:proposalNumber]];
        // While the current index value is less than the length of the array write the GPS values into our file then take a new line.
        for(int i=0;i <= allGPS.count;i++){
            if(i < allGPS.count){
                saveGPS = [allGPS objectAtIndex:i];
                csvString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@ %d, %@, %@", [saveGPS sourceReceiver], [[saveGPS positionNo] intValue], [saveGPS latitude], [saveGPS longitude]];
                [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
                [myHandle writeData:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
            else if (i == allGPS.count){
                @synchronized(FilePath) {
                    // Checks if the device can send email.
                    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
                        // Sets the subject to data from (our current proposal number).
                        [mail setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data from %@", proposalNumber]];
                        [mail setMessageBody:@"Please see the attached .CSV file." isHTML:NO];
                        // Finds the .CSV file we just saved, and attaches it to the email.
                        NSData *myattachment = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", FilePath]];
                        [mail addAttachmentData:myattachment mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",proposalNumber]];
                        // Opens up the email screen.
                        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Creates a popup window to inform the user that their email wasn't able to send.
                        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                       message:@"Unable to send email. Have you set up a mail account on this device?"
                                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                        UIAlertAction* dismissAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
                        alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
                        [alert addAction:dismissAction];
                        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
[mail addAttachmentData:myattachment mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",proposalNumber]];
```

you're setting the mime type but the file name doesn't contain an extension. Mac OS X is intelligent enough to work out what to do by looking at the mime type and potentially the file contents. Windows isn't. Windows is much more reliant on the actual file extension.

Add the file extension to the name of the file as it's attached to the e-mail.

Comment: Note that iOS uses the *nix convention for newlines, i.e. it ends each line of the csv with a LF (line feed). Windows expects CR LF (carriage return, line feed) instead. This can cause problems when importing the data later on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, feel pretty stupid having made this mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the extension ".xls", not csv. Use ".csv" as your extension.

Comment: That's a mistake, I tried out a xls library to write a .xls instead of a .csv in order to solve this issue and forgot to change it back, thanks for the reminder.